# Named entity recognition - tagging tools

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

Does someone have a recommendation of tagging tool for NER types in raw text?

The input for the tool should be a library of text files(.txt simple format) , there should be a convenient UI for selecting words and set the tag/annotation fit to selection, the output should be structural representations of the tags(e.gs tart index , last index, tag in a JSON format)

Answer (score 1):

Founderof [LightTag](http://lighttag.io) here

We provide a super convenient interface to do span annotations such as named entity recognition, classifications and relationships. 
You can work as one labeler or bring in a team and LightTag will disribute work between everyone automatically (no more selecting files and remembering what you labeled already) . 
[image]

You can upload your own suggestions and let labelers use those, or use LightTags built in model.
Of course you can annotate at the character level and highlight subwords or multi word phrases. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you Tal, worth updating your comment with LightTag latest updates?

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/lasigeBioTM/MER (bash)
see the demo at http://labs.fc.ul.pt/mer/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I'm after.
I need to choose words from given raw text and label them/

Answer (score 0):

**Online tools:**

I guess Dataturks' POS tool should work fine for your use case, you can just upload your data and specify the labels. The UI seems convenient enough.

Here is the link:
https://dataturks.com

It's an online tool, so you can work with multiple people to get the tagging done.

The exact output format you are looking for is not supported, but the format can easily be converted to what you are looking for, the output is like: word___LABEL word2___LABEL , so a simple 2-line script can convert it to start and end index.

**Offline:**

Another tool you can check out is prodigy, it's a downloadable software and does similar things. Just that you might be willing to pay for it upfront.
https://prodi.gy